# DER Encoding Public Key created by cryptopp is different then openssl

Tags: crypto++

I've been trying to create a DER encoded public key using an RSA private key.  The way I normally create it is using the command line:

```
openssl rsa -pubout -outform DER -in ~/.keys/api_key.pem -out der_pub.der
```

When I use CryptoPP to create this file, they are slightly different.  It seems it has an extra section.  The one created by openssl has a little extra section. I'm assuming this is the BIT STRING mentioned in the CryptoPP API. https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_r_s_a_function.html

```
void    DEREncodePublicKey (BufferedTransformation &bt) const
encode subjectPublicKey part of subjectPublicKeyInfo, without the BIT STRING header
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
    ...
    CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey rsaPrivate;
    rsaPrivate.BERDecodePrivateKey(queue, false /*paramsPresent*/, queue.MaxRetrievable());

    CryptoPP::ByteQueue bq;
    rsaPrivate.DEREncodePublicKey(bq);
    CryptoPP::FileSink fs1("cryptopp_pub.der", true);
    bq.TransferTo(fs1);
```

Comment: Also see [Keys and Formats](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats) on the Crypto++ wiki. Since you are writing the *subjectPublicKeyInfo* with OpenSSL, use *`Load(...)`* (and not *`BERDecode(...)`*) in Crypto++.

Comment: It is OK to supply an answer for your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm still researching and I've tried to use Load() directly and still does not produce the same DER cert.  I will get back with an answer once I found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [CryptoPP::RSA::DEREncodePublicKey](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_r_s_a_function.html#ab962ade2ef1ddd37fdef57fe7e5e5a40) encodes subjectPublicKey part of subjectPublicKeyInfo, *without the BIT STRING header*

Try `CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey::DEREncode`. Being careful to apply this to only the *public* key, as RSA::PrivateKey does overload the DEREncode method.

Here I'm using CryptoPP 8.2

1. Load DER encoded private key from disk

   ```cpp
   CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey private_key;
   {
       CryptoPP::FileSource file{"my.key", true};
       private_key.BERDecodePrivateKey(file, false, -1);
   }
   ```
2. Save out DER encoded public key

   ```cpp
   CryptoPP::FileSink sink{"my.pub", true};
   CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey{private_key}.DEREncode(sink);
   ```

OpenSSL:

```sh
# generate a new RSA private key (DER format)
openssl genrsa | openssl rsa -outform DER -out my.key

# hash/fingerprint the public key
openssl rsa -in my.key -inform DER -pubout -outform DER | openssl sha256
writing RSA key
362945ad4a5f87f27d3db3b4adbacaee0ebc3f778ee2fe76ef4fb09933148372

# compare against hash of our code sample's generated public key
cat my.pub | openssl sha256
362945ad4a5f87f27d3db3b4adbacaee0ebc3f778ee2fe76ef4fb09933148372
```

---

As another example; if we want CryptoPP to generate a SHA256 fingerprint:

```cpp
std::string hash_out_str;
{
    CryptoPP::SHA256 sha256;
    CryptoPP::HashFilter filter{
        sha256,
        new CryptoPP::HexEncoder{
            new CryptoPP::StringSink{hash_out_str}
        }
    };
    CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey{private_key}.DEREncode(filter); // intentionally slice to ensure we aren't exposing a public key
    filter.MessageEnd();
}
std::cout << hash_out_str << '\n';
```

Outputs:

```
362945AD4A5F87F27D3DB3B4ADBACAEE0EBC3F778EE2FE76EF4FB09933148372
```

i.e., we need to copy/slice to a RSA::PublicKey to invoke the OpenSSL compatible DER encoding method